# How to obtain minimum from anonymous set of expressions in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a set of three `double` values as part of an anonymous expression in a LINQ query.  It looks something like this:

```
from item in collection where
     Min(val1-val2, item.Property1, somethingElse) > item.Property2
     select item;
```

How do I obtain the minimum of the expressions in parenthesis?  Math.Min only accepts two arguments.  Should I just use an anonymous List.Min()?  Are there better approaches?

Comment: Are all val1-val2, somethingElse independent from the collection? If so, you need to calculate the expression only once.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more to the point.  They do all depend on item actually.  But good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = collection
    .Where(i => new[] { val1 - val2, item.Property1, somethingElse }.Min() > i.Property2)
```

Alternatively you could just use `Min` twice i.e. `Min(val1 - val2, Min(item.Property1, somethingElse))`. If `val1 - val2` and `somethingElse` are constant, then you can move it outside the `Where` clause which will make things simpler as well.

```
double min = Min(val1 - val2, somethingElse);
var items = collection.Where(i => Min(min, item.Property1) > i.Property2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `val1 - val2` and `somethingElse` are not dependent on `item`, you can do a simple trick:

```
var tempMin = Math.Min(val1-val2, somethingElse);
from item in collection where
     Math.Min(item.Property1, tempMin) > item.Property2
     select item;
```

Otherwise, you can go with

```
from item in collection where
     Math.Min(item.Property1, Math.Min(val1-val2, somethingElse)) > item.Property2
     select item;
```

If the number of items to compare is potentially big or not known in advance, you can go with Lee's version.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could use `Min` extension method in a following way:

```
from item in collection where
(new[] { val1-val2, item.Property1, somethingElse }.Min()) > item.Property2
select item;
```

However, this would result in a new array being instantiated for each `item` in a `collection`. This may not be the best approach, performance-wise. It is much better to write a simple method to get minimal of three values:

```
public double Min(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double result = a;

    if (result < b)
    {
       result = b;
    }

    if (result < c)
    {
       result = c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then, you can write the following query:

```
from item in collection where
Min(val1-val2, item.Property1, somethingElse) > item.Property2
select item;
```